# How to change data definitions in datatable of yui?

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, yui

I am using YUI to develop web application. I can create and update from dynamic xml. There is no problems for update data but the problems is header is not change. How I can inject new header or column definition to the datatbles. Here are code I useung

```
//This part is not run.
ajaxtable.oDT.responseSchema = {
    resultNode: "element",
    fields: Fields
};
ajaxtable.oDT.aColumnDefs=ColumnDefs;

// This part is run properly.
ajaxtable.oDT.getDataSource().sendRequest("param="+link,
    {success: ajaxtable.oDT.onDataReturnInitializeTable},
ajaxtable.oDT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understood your question, but it seems like what your looking for is the the formatter property in the column definition.

```
{key:"type", label: "", sortable:true, formatter: "formatIcon"}
```

Implement it like this:

```
YAHOO.widget.DataTable.Formatter.formatIcon = function(elLiner, oRecord, oColumn, oData) { };
```

Take a look [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/#format) for more information.